# Is $\int_0^1 \frac{x^p}{1＋x^q} \;dx < \infty$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

When $p>-1, \;q>0$, is the following true?

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^p}{1＋x^q}\; dx < \infty$$

Any help would be appreciated. I observed by graph soft this may be true, but I’m not certain. Thank you.

Comment: May be will be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741261/determine-if-int-1-infty-fracdxxpxq-converges/3741315#3741315

Answer (score 3):

If $q>0$ and $x \in [0,1]$, then $1 \le 1+x^q \le 2$, so
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}\;dx
$$
converges if and only if
$$
\int_0^1 x^p\;dx
$$
converges.  That is, if $p>-1$.

Comment: thank you! Is my claim true?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $p>-1$ and $q>0$ then, if $x\in (0,1)$,

$$\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}=\frac{x^{p-q}}{x^{-q}+1}<x^{p-q}.$$

Comment: then, if p＝-1/2, q＝１０、the integral is not finite, so my claim is false?

Answer (score 0):

With *Asymptotic Analysis*:

Near $0$, $\:1+x^q\sim 1$, hence
$$\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}\sim_0 x^p,$$
and $\displaystyle\int_0^1\!x^p\,\mathrm dx<\infty$ if $p>-1$.